# Feed a tensor to a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code, representing an adversarial model. As an input, it takes an image with size 150x150x3 and a model to advertise. Basic idea is to add some noise to the picture and then to predict, using the given `classifier_model`.

```
def build_adversarial_model(img, classifier_model):

  get_custom_objects().update({'clip': layers.Activation(clip)})

  for layer in classifier_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
  image = layers.Input(name='original_image',
                       shape=img.shape)
  one = layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='unity')

  noise = layers.Dense(units=150,
                       activation=None,
                       use_bias=False,
                       kernel_initializer='random_normal',
                       kernel_regularizer=l2(.1),
                       name='adversarial_noise'
                       )(one)

  res = layers.Reshape(img.shape, name='reshape')(noise)
  x = layers.Add(name='add')([image, res])

  # Clip values to be within 0 and 1
  x = layers.Activation('clip')(x)
  output = classifier_model.predict(x)
  adversarial_model = Model(inputs=[image, one],
                            outputs=[output])
  adversarial_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy')

  return adversarial_model

def clip(x):
  '''Custom activation function for clipping adversarial pixel values.'''
  return K.clip(x, 0., 1.)
```

It fails at `output = classifier_model.predict(x)`, saying:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

What causes this error and how can I avoid it in the future? Neither `img`, nor `classifier_model` are none, dimensions seem to be well-scaled.

Comment: it means that x is NoneType, check the value of x which is passed into predict function

Comment: x is not NoneType. It's a Tensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.predict` takes a numpy array, you have a symbolic tensor, what you should do is:

```
output = classifier_model(x)
```